# Writing elements of std::map through iteration

Tags: c++, stl

I have written the following code...

```
  PagesMap::const_iterator end = pagesMap.end(); 
  for ( PagesMap::const_iterator it = pagesMap.begin(); it != end; ++it )
  {
    ....
    it->second = 0; // Here I get the error
    //pagesMap[it->first] = 0; 
  }
```

Now at line where I have `it->second = 0;`, I get...

*error: assignment of data-member ‘std::pair::second’ in read-only structure*

If I use the commented code below that line, it works, but It's my guess that it is not efficient. Is there an efficient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's because you are using a `const_iterator`; try changing to an `iterator` instead.